# setting DBT_PROFILES_DIR in cmder

Tags: visual-studio-code, zsh, dbt, zshrc, cmder

my team and I are upgrading to dbt 1.5. and I want the change of search-order for the dbt profile.yml file as easy as possible. For MacOS I successfully tested the solution of

```
echo "export DBT_PROFILES_DIR=~/.dbt" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Unfortunately not all of us have a MacOS but they are using the cmder. Is there a way to make something similiar for the cmder config?

I should mention that this has to run in VS Code. I tried to change the vscode_init.cmd but it did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is to set it as an environment variable.

```
setx DBT_PROFILES_DIR C:\%your_path_here%\.dbt
```